# Tell me how to filter data by uniqueness. Data is received upon request, I want to summarize only unique data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

> Just like when you select select 4, the total goes into 4, and when
> you select 5, the total goes into + 5, but you need +1, because there
> is only one unique loaded image. I'm trying to do it through the
> filter, but so far without success.Tell me, am I thinking correctly?

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Cat, fetchCats } from "../api/services/CatsService";
import { DropdownMenu, MenuItem } from "./Dropdown/Dropdown";
import { Header } from "./Header/Header";
import { Select } from "./Select/Select";

    enter code here

export function MainPage() {
  const [cats, setCats] = useState<Cat[]>([]);
  const [numberInSelect, setOption] = useState<number>(
    Number(localStorage.getItem("numberInSelect") || 3)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("numberInSelect", JSON.stringify(numberInSelect));
    const cachedData = localStorage.getItem("someData");

    const parse = JSON.parse(cachedData);
    if (cachedData) {
      if (parse.length < numberInSelect) {
        fetchCats(numberInSelect - parse.length).then((data) => {
          const array = [];
          array.push(...data);
          array.push(...parse);
          localStorage.setItem("someData", JSON.stringify(array));
          setCats(array);
        });
      }

      const rew = parse.slice(0, numberInSelect);
      setCats(rew);
    } else {
      fetchCats(numberInSelect).then((data) => {
        localStorage.setItem("someData", JSON.stringify(data));
        setCats(data);
      });
    }
  }, [numberInSelect]);

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <Header title={"Всего котов загружено:"} option={numberInSelect} />

        <Select
          label={"Pick a number"} //вызов
          options={[3, 4, 5]}
          title={"Cats"}
          setCats={setCats}
          setOption={setOption}
          option={numberInSelect}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="title-list-info">
        {" "}
        <CatList title="Cats list: " cats={cats} />
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I'm afraid there's not enough context in the question for your code or the description to make any sense. Can you please edit to provide more useful detail

Comment: yes, i'm corrected my code

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you're trying to dynamically load cat images based on the selected number in a dropdown. If I understand correctly, you want to ensure that even if the selected number is greater than the number of unique loaded images, it should still display the available unique images without duplicating them.

```
export function MainPage() {
  const [cats, setCats] = useState<Cat[]>([]);
  const [numberInSelect, setOption] = useState<number>(
    Number(localStorage.getItem("numberInSelect") || 3)
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("numberInSelect", JSON.stringify(numberInSelect));

    const cachedData = localStorage.getItem("someData");
    const parse = JSON.parse(cachedData);

    if (cachedData) {
      if (parse.length < numberInSelect) {
        fetchCats(numberInSelect - parse.length).then((data) => {
          const array = [...data, ...parse];
          localStorage.setItem("someData", JSON.stringify(array));
          setCats(array);
        });
      } else {
        const uniqueCats = parse.slice(0, numberInSelect);
        setCats(uniqueCats);
      }
    } else {
      fetchCats(numberInSelect).then((data) => {
        localStorage.setItem("someData", JSON.stringify(data));
        setCats(data);
      });
    }
  }, [numberInSelect]);

  // Add your rendering logic here using the 'cats' state.

  return (
    <div>
      {/* Your rendering logic for displaying cat images based on the 'cats' state */}
    </div>
  );
}

// Replace this with your actual fetch function
async function fetchCats(count: number): Promise<Cat[]> {
  // Add your logic to fetch cat images
  // Return an array of cat objects
  return [];
}

interface Cat {
  // Define the structure of your Cat object
}
```

Comment: Did you generate this answer?

Comment: I had a similar problem a few weeks ago, adapt a code I already had

Comment: ok, but i have  components Cat with interface Cat and export async function fetchCats(limit: number = 1): Promise<Cat[]> {
  const response = await fetch(
    `https://api.thecatapi.com/v1/images/search?limit=${limit}`,
    options
  );
  const data: Cat[] = await response.json();
  return data;
}

Comment: This is how things get complicated...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1